# ORA-24920 but text is shorter than column size

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a varchar2(16000 char) column, for really long texts. I can insert longer than 4000 char texts into this column, but when I try to select it through sqldeveloper I get an ORA-24920 error. If I skip that column from my query, I get some data back, and if I check the length of the column, I get back the correct length of the inserted text.

The problem is that it seems that sqldeveloper cannot handle this long text. Any idea?

Comment: Could the text be in UTF8?  that may tell you ~4000 characters, but it would be a lot more bytes than an ascii 4k chars.

Comment: But how it can be happened, even if the text is UTF8, that I can insert a long text into the database, but cannot query that? I think that it's some sqldeveloper preference issue, but I couldn't find where should I change something...

Comment: I'm sorry, I misread your question.  You are able to successfully insert correct? but you are having trouble querying the inserted value?

Comment: Excactly. I've no idea what to do, and I use sqldeveloper.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless you're using Oracle 12c, SQL tables have a limit of 4000 characters on VARCHAR2.

This is a little confusing because PL/SQL variables have a VARCHAR2 limit of 32k, which means you could declare a VARCHAR2(16000) variable in a procedure and have it try to insert into a table which will work as long as the data is below the SQL limit.

In Oracle 12c, the SQL table limit for VARCHAR2 can be expanded to 32k if [MAX_STRING_SIZE](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/REFRN/GUID-D424D23B-0933-425F-BC69-9C0E6724693C.htm) property is set to EXTENDED.

If your database version is already 12c, then you need to upgrade your SQL Developer to the latest version, [see here.](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/overview/index.html) Apparently older versions can't handle the expanded SQL VARCHAR2 limit and will give you the error you're seeing.

Comment: I asked our administrators about our database and they said it's actually 12c. My sqldeveloper version is 4.0.2.15 which is the latest one afaik. Any idea?

Comment: Your version does not support select of anything past 4k yet.

https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=43135:7:0::NO::P7_ID:39941

Comment: I don't think there's anything more we can tell you. All signs point to somewhere in your stack not supporting 12c. Just for kicks, run the following query- SELECT * FROM V$VERSION; . That will tell you what version your database is, but if you were able to create the table with a VARCHAR2 size above 4k, then it seems like the IDE is the issue and not the database.

Comment: I'm hundred percent sure that sqldeveloper is wrong, I was wondering that there's some option to force 32k support, but based on this topic and the latest conversation it seems that it's a missing feature from sqldeveloper, so we have to wait for the next release. Thanks anyway!