# Extended length for varchar2 in Oracle 12c

Tags: oracle, varchar2

I thought I should give the new extended varchar2 limits in my Java application.  Here's what I've done so far:

1. Changed MAX_STRING_SIZE to EXTENDED according to the recommended procedure.
2. Extended the column in question to 32767 characters.
3. Ran the program.

Java call `ResultSet.updateString( str, idx )` runs fine, but when I come to ResultSet.updateRow(), I end up in a Java exception referring to an Oracle error:

> java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01461: can bind a LONG value only for insert into a LONG column

Complete error stack (or at least the part that doesn't refer to my code) follows:

```
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01461: can bind a LONG value only for insert into a LONG column
at oracle.jdbc.driver.SQLStateMapping.newSQLException(SQLStateMapping.java:70)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.newSQLException(DatabaseError.java:112)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:173)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:455)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:413)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.receive(T4C8Oall.java:1030)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:194)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForRows(T4CPreparedStatement.java:947)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1222)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3381)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3462)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.UpdatableResultSet.executeUpdateRow(UpdatableResultSet.java:3317)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.UpdatableResultSet.updateRow(UpdatableResultSet.java:2281)
```

As far as I can reckon, this should be it.  But either I have forgotten something fundamental, or this must be a bug (perhaps in the jdbc library).

Comment: which character set are you using in your database ? in UTF8 Latin 1 characters are expanded and the total size is increased. Example: You will see the string length is 32 characters but when encoded using UTF8 the size increases to 34 characters. Please confirm this setting and provide a table description + a row update example.

Comment: I have managed to dig further into the error message causes, and ended up with a ora-24920 error.  I am using sqldeveloper and other java based tools, so it seems to me that the problem is java or jdbc related, and not sql.<br>
It is most likely related to this thread [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24829223/ora-24920-but-text-is-shorter-than-column-size)

Answer (score 1):

You must use the JDBC driver from 12c.